# What is this and what is the purpose of it?

Tags: car-rentals, identify-this

I saw this one in my  rent a car but I am not too sure the purpose of it as no heat is going out of it? Is it just decoration?
[image: Car]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about tourism.

Comment: Heat comes out easily when you engage de-fog mode in air conditioner

Comment: Sorry, but questions about "how does my car work?" are off-topic, here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby but this is a question about how a rental car works.

Comment: @phoog It doesn't make any difference who owns the car.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree.  There are other questions here about things that might be encountered by travelers or might be encountered by people living in their own towns.  There's an entire category of questions ([tag:identify-this]) that survives essentially because a community of travelers is well suited to answer rather than because the questions themselves are about travel.  In fact, under the current version of the tag wiki, this question arguably belongs in the category, since rental cars are a "travel-related thing."

Comment: @phoog In that case, anything at all involving cars applies to rental cars, so all questions about cars are now on topic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I disagree with that, too.  This is about identifying the purpose and function of something in an unfamiliar car.  It is a problem I certainly face very frequently since I do not own a car, and anyone renting a car might face it.  In this case, the feature is literally right in front of the driver's face, and it happens to be a feature that the driver should understand.  That doesn't mean that questions about (for example) choosing motor oil are on topic.  The renter of a car does not generally make choices about the car's maintenance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's for removing condensation from the side window.  Air comes out of it only in the defrost/defog settings.

Comment: So you could see the side mirror clearly..

Comment: Cool - I learned something!